# Starting an activity as a Thread?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently struggling to create a mobile (Android) version of a "battleship" program I recently coded. While my GUI is finished by now and most parts of the program should work, I have (at least) one main problem left: the main part of my program besides the server part (which will react to user input, etc.) relies on Java NIO, i.e. network access. However, since it's running on the main thread, I receive

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{x.battleship/x.battleship.BattleshipMain}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`
```

(I replaced the package name with x for privacy reasons).

Hence, my question is: how can I start an activity as a new Thread? so far, i have used

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BattleshipMain.class);
startActivity(i);
i.putExtra("ip",joinip);
i.putExtra("port",joinport);
```

at first, i thought this would be an alternative:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BattleshipMain.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            i.putExtra("ip",joinip);
                            i.putExtra("port",joinport);
                        }
                    });
```

However, it doesn't seem to work - I get a message in the console, that `BattleshipMain` has been started, but nothing actually shows up on the display (except whatever was there already).
does anybody have an idea what to do? I really don't know how to solve this; I'm still new to Android, though, and not really a long-term expert in java either.

Thanks in advance!

//edit: I'm not too familiar if I'm supposed to do this, but after I moved the networking code to a separate thread, it seems to me that I'm unable to connect the app on my phone to a server running on my PC. They're in the same network & the server should be compatible with the mobile app, but considering the errors / freeze screens I receive, I don't see what else could be the problem.
Does Java NIO work normally on android at all / could I possibly connect a client on my phone (which is a Galaxy S3, btw -> API 18) to a server on a PC with Windows?
Thank you! :)

//edit: nevermind, the error was 100% dumb. When using an Intent to create a new activity, i created the intent, launched it, and THEN used intentname.putExtra(key, value) - which obviously didn't work. Right now, I got another error because I tried to change a checkBox from a different thread, but the network part worked, so I guess I'll be done soon.

Comment: You cannot run the Activity on a non-UI thread. You need to move your network code onto a UI thread. The network code that you have inside your Activity.

Comment: The keyword is Network in `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, meaning you are doing some network access stuff, and Android doesn't like that. If you added more code, we could solve your [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Knossos I believe you mean you need to move your network code off the UI thread.

Comment: Oops! Yes! Network code needs to be moved onto a BACKGROUND thread.

Comment: well, that was what i feared i'd have to do ... the network stuff worked so nicely in the windows application, i'm not really eager to separate it. well, i guess i'll have to now :(
Thank you anyways, though! :)

Comment: See my answer here for a detailed example. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35210468/2308683

Comment: I presume you are not a native android developer but you should be familiar with restclients (like Spring).So why not try using something like retrofit/okhttp ?

Comment: @droidekas: well, considering the battleship program is my first ever java program (except for hello world) ... no, i'm not familar with restclients ^^
although i've found that there's another error (that might solve the network problem) - when launching an activity, i used and intent & intentName.putExtra(key, value) for the parameters. later, i used Bundle b = intentname.getExtras() in the new activity, and b.get(key) to get the values. however, this doesn't seem to work. i guess i'll google the usage of "intent extras", and not do it the way i read it somewhere else ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're doing networking on the main thread, which is prohibited. Move all networking and network/api calls into `AsyncTask`s and it should be good to go.

EDIT:
apart from that, please, abandon the idea of starting activities as threads, as Activities have their own lifecycle [which is described here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

EDIT2: perhaps if you manage to turn off StrictMode (available in developer options) you could do networking on the main thread but... i wouldn't count on it.

Comment: `networking on the main thread` please forget those words and never ever say them again

Comment: @Droidman why? the man had a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` show up in the logcat - he's the one that should forget about them, not me :)

Comment: because of the beginner folks that see such hints and start looking for "hacks" to run network on the main thread instead of "bothering" with background networking. This results in crappy software and total misunderstanding of how Android works.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what's written up there, but I can still clearly see 

"The problem you're having is that you're doing networking on the main thread, which is prohibited. Move all networking and network/api calls into AsyncTasks and it should be good to go."

Comment: I didn't say your answer is incorrect, I just don't like the idea of mentioning the ways to allow network on the main thread, at least *without explaining why this is bad and strongly recommending not to do so*. But nvm, this is just my personal opinion

Comment: I'm sorry but our opinions differ - if it were **that** terrible, it would've been prohibited just like writing to `/system` is. But because there is a way, obviously someone figured it would be nice to address that need. And since there is a way, you might as well use it.

Comment: I appreciate your worries, @Droidman, but I can assure you I have no intentions of utilizing any "hacks" so I don't have to move my networking to a separate thread. a) that's probably more work than actually moving the network part, and b) since I know now that I'm not allowed to do network stuff on my main thread, I won't structure my program this way in the future. Aside from that, I'd be interested in why exactly using these hacks would be bad - i guess there's some reason why Google disabled that, right?

Comment: @Misteradi1 different people will give you different answers, but I found out that sometimes the answer pretty much devolves to "because the tutorials say so!"... Truth is, nothing bad happens if you allow networking on main thread, you (as a regular user/developer) just can't do it. So better get used to doing it properly and fall back to alternative "hacky" solutions when the default one simply can't solve the issue. Because they are allowed **just for those special occasions when nothing else will work** :D Perhaps droidman will explain why it's really bad.

Comment: It is considered bad practice to do networking on the main thread because that will cause a bad user interface experience. The main thread is also called the UI thread because the user interface is driven from that thread. If you do a long-running operation on the main thread, you will block the system from doing updates to the UI and thus your app freezes until the operation is over. So you can do short operations on the main thread, but not long ones like networking operations that may take seconds or even minutes.

Comment: @RobMeeuwisse got the point. Networking is a **blocking** operation that will cause your UI to freeze, possibly for a long period of time. `you can do short operations on the main thread` - you should also avoid CPU-intensive operations on the UI thread, no matter whether they are short or not

Comment: P.S. To quantify short and long operations on the main thread: a long operation is roughly anything that takes more than 10 or 15 milliseconds. A smooth user interface experience is achieved when the screen is refreshed at 60 frames per second. Meaning there is 16 milliseconds per frame to do that (1 second divided by 60 frames). If you eat up all the time available to draw a frame then the system will have to skip that frame. The user will notice this as screen jitter.

Comment: Incidentally, a UI blocking operation lasting more than 5 seconds will cause an [ANR](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/articles/perf-anr.html). These should be avoided like the plague. This is why Google introduced the NetworkingOnMainThreadException (in API level 11). It is so bad, they forced Apps to just crash instead of letting bad code into Apps in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I remember when that started to happen, somewhere around ICS... They're not exactly crashing, per see, as clicking 'wait' usually lets them finish their business. While I do agree that non responsiveness should be avoided, sometimes those happen due to insufficient testing :/

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You have exactly one UI thread.