# Using AsyncTask with passing a value

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have been working on this and I have hit a point where I dont know what to do. What I am trying to do is use one class to download and parse out a file into a string and then send that string to another class to parse out the JSON stuff. All the parts work fine by themselves and I have tested everything separately. I just dont know how to send the value to the Json parses to start the parsing.

So this is my filedownloader class.

```
  public class JsonFileDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  //used to access the website
  String username = "admin";
  String password = "admin";
  public String ret = "";



  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      Log.d("Params ", params[0].toString());
      readFromFile(params[0]);
      return ret;
  }

  private String readFromFile(String myWebpage) {

      HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

      try {
          //Get the url connection
          URL url = new URL(myWebpage);
          Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
              @Override
             protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()   {
                  return new PasswordAuthentication(username,   password.toCharArray());
            }
          });
          urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

          InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();


          if (inputStream != null) {
              ret = streamToString(inputStream);
              inputStream.close();
              Log.d("Final String", ret);
          }

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          if (urlConnection != null) {
              urlConnection.disconnect();
          }
          return ret;

      }
  }
  public static String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException   {

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line);
      }
       return sb.toString();
   }

  public String getJsonData()
  {
      return ret;
   }
```

}

This works fine I have tested it over and over with no errors.
The next is the Json parser which is like this.

```
public class JSONParser {

JSONObject jsonResponse;
String jsonData;

//Consturctor
public JSONParser()
{
    //this.jsonData = jsonData;
    // this.OutputData = outPutData;
}

public void parsesData(String promo,
                       ArrayList<String> pictureHTTP,
                       ArrayList<String> pathHTTP,
                       ArrayList<String> labelText) throws IOException {

    //Build the Json String
    JsonFileDownloader jfd = new JsonFileDownloader();
   // jsonData = String.valueOf(jfd.execute(promo));
    jfd.execute(promo);
    //jfd.getResuts(jsonData);
    //jsonData = jfd.ret;

    Log.d("JsonData String = " , jsonData);


    //Try to parse the data
    try
    {

        Log.d("Jsondata " , jsonData);
        //Creaate a new JSONObject ith the name/value mapping from the JSON string
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        //Returns the value mapped by the name if it exists and is a JSONArry
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("");

        //Proccess the JSON node
        int lenghtJsonArrar = jsonMainNode.length();
        for (int i = 0; i<lenghtJsonArrar; i++)
        {
            //Get object for each json node
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            //Get the node values
            //int song_id = Integer.parseInt(jsonChildNode.optString("song_id").toString());
            String picture = jsonChildNode.optString("picture").toString();
            String pathName = jsonChildNode.optString("path").toString();
            String lableName = jsonChildNode.optString("label".toString());
            //Debug Testing code
            pictureHTTP.add(picture);
            pathHTTP.add(pathName);
            labelText.add(lableName);


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Now I know where the problem is occurring. When i try to assign a value to the jsonData it never is assigned so it is null and the system fails.
I have tried a few things after the jfd.exicute() but I just dont know how to get the value from the final string output into the jsonData. 
Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: Just because you put your `try` block after executing `JsonFileDownloader` does not mean the `AsyncTask` will finish processing by then. Instead, use `onPostExecute` from your `AsyncTask` to process the return value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, here is a pretty flexible pattern for the overall usage of using AsyncTask to download web content and getting the results from it back to the UI thread.

**Step 1** Define an interface that will act as a message bus between the AsyncTask and where you want the data.

```
public interface AsyncResponse<T> {
    void onResponse(T response);
}
```

**Step 2** Create a generic AsyncTask extension that will take any URL and return the results from it. You basically had this already, but I made some tweaks. Most importantly, allowing the setting of the AsyncResponse callback interface.

```
public class WebDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private AsyncResponse<String> callback;

    // Optional parameters
    private String username;
    private String password;

    // Make a constuctor to store the parameters
    public WebDownloadTask(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // Don't forget to call this
    public void setCallback(AsyncResponse<String> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        return readFromFile(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onResponse(s);
        } else {
            Log.w(WebDownloadTask.class.getSimpleName(), "The response was ignored");
        }
    }

    /******* private helper methods *******/

    private String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String readFromFile(String myWebpage) {

        String response = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            //Get the url connection
            URL url = new URL(myWebpage);

            // Unnecessary for general AsyncTask usage
            /* 
            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
                }
            });
            */

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            if (inputStream != null) {
                response = streamToString(inputStream);
                inputStream.close();
                Log.d("Final String", response);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Step 3** Go forth and use that AsyncTask wherever you wish. Here is an example. Note that if you do not use `setCallback`, you will be unable to get the data that came from the AsyncTask.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebDownloadTask task = new WebDownloadTask("username", "password");
        task.setCallback(new AsyncResponse<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Handle response here. E.g. parse into a JSON object
                // Then put objects into some list, then place into an adapter... 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Use any URL, this one returns a list of 10 users in JSON
        task.execute("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that fixed it, I didnt know I had to make a Asynctask interface this really helps out a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't **have to**, it is just a common pattern using the standard Java libraries to use interfaces as asynchronous callbacks.