# Why is return registration successful?

Tags: android, database

```php
require "findDoctorConnect.php";
$type = $_POST["type"];
$yourName = $_POST["YourName"];
$RegNum = $_POST["regNum"];
$FatherName = $_POST["fatherName"];
$Gender = $_POST["gender"];
$MobileNumber = $_POST["mobileNumber"];
$Password = $_POST["password"];
$sql_query = "select * from doctorregistration where MobileNumber='$MobileNumber';";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $temp = $row["MobileNumber"];
    if ($temp == $MobileNumber) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "already found";
    }
} else if (mysqli_query($con, $sql_query)) {
    $sql_query = "insert into doctorregistration values('$type','$yourName','$RegNum','$FatherName','$Gender','$MobileNumber','$Password');";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query);
    echo "successfull";
}
```

When I send data from my application to database, first time it's saved in database and it returns registration successfully, but when again with same data like my primary key is mobile number when I send data to database it again said me that registration successful but actually it does not save data this time. I want to return registration unsuccessful so what to do for that?

Here is my code:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context ctx;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
    }

    public BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String reg_url="http://10.0.2.2/findDoctor/register.php";
        String method=params[0];
        if(method.equals("register")) {
            String type=params[1];
            String YourName=params[2];
            String regNum=params[3];
            String fatherName=params[4];
            String gender=params[5];
            String mobileNumber=params[6];
            String password=params[7];

            try {
                URL url=new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream OS=connection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS));
                String Data=URLEncoder.encode("type","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(type,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("YourName","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(YourName,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("regNum","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regNum,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("fatherName","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(fatherName,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("gender","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(gender,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("mobileNumber","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(mobileNumber,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(Data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS=connection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                return "registration successful";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
        if (result.endsWith("Registration seccussfull")) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if(result.endsWith("already found")){
            alertDialog.setMessage("its works");
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmHQI.png)

Comment: Typo in onPostExecute? `"Registration seccussfull"`

Comment: You can see an answer I wrote here about using AsyncTask in a good way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209769/using-asycntask-with-passing-a-value/35210468#35210468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage this condition on server side `http://10.0.2.2/findDoctor/register.php` and return some data to android code.

And in android read the data from server using `InputStream` and then check if registered success or not.

**Edit : Add these lines and it will show proper output**

```
InputStream IS=connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS));
String line;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
    builder.append(line);
IS.close();
return builder.toString();
```

These lines says that, you don't care about the server response.

Comment: can you suggest me how to do that its my final year project i am stuck here

Comment: thanks alot for your help i was trying this for last 2 days thanks alot sir