# Trouble listing all the values from my database in my ListView

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to list all the values in my `localhost database` into a `ListView`. Basically, the `REST` process and background stuff happens in my `AsyncTask` class so I can't really use the `onCreate` method.

Anyways, this is my code:

```
public class ViewNames extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> viewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewnames);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // If I add the adapter here then I can't view the results. I want to view all the values I have as soon
        as I open up the form. But this process only happens in my AsyncTask class so I don't know how to model this
        list
        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewNames.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result);
        //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

public class ViewNamesJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {  

    ... //Other methods go here. They work fine.

    @Override
    // This is where it doesn't work. If I display the adapter in onCreate then I have an empty list.
    // But I want to display the results of all the values after the user has clicked the button.
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        List<String> namesList = new List<String>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("names");

            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject ones = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String names = ones.optString("names");
                namesList.add(names);
            }
            String[] result = namesList.toArray(new String[namesList.size()]);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewNames.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My `XML` file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".ViewNames"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Names"
        android:id="@+id/addNamesButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am having some difficulty, because I want to instantly display everything from my database into the `ListView` and then for the `ListView` to update when the user clicks the button.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can define and add the adapter in `onCreate`. It's just a matter of invoking `notifyDataSetChanged` on it when task is completed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using AsyncTask with passing a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209769/using-asynctask-with-passing-a-value)

Comment: try adding after  (listView.setAdapter(adapter);) (adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();)

Comment: You should consider to include a spinner and list view in your activity layout,   during on create show the spinner and create adapter object and set the adapter to list view but make its visibility gone. Later once you got the response received then update the array adapter with newly received string[] and then notify data set changed, you should use a separate method refreshListView(String[] items) to do this and inside this method hide spinner and make your list view visible if its gone state.

Comment: An ArrayAdapter can take a list, you don't need to `namesList.toArray`

Comment: Where do you execute the AsyncTask? It doesn't just happen automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define and add the adapter in `onCreate`. It's just a matter of invoking `notifyDataSetChanged` on it when task is completed.

You can proceed as follows, by passing a `List` to the adapter instead of an array, so that Activity and Adapter share the same collection.

```
public class ViewNames extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    List<String> result;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewnames);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        result = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewNames.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        (new ViewNamesJSON()).execute();
    }

    public class ViewNamesJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        // Other methods go here. They work fine.

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("names");

                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject ones = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String names = ones.optString("names");
                    namesList.add(names);
                }
                result.clear();
                result.addAll(namesList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I still can't view anything in my ListView. The ListView is not even displayed on the form

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz are you sure you are not copying the list in some way? It's important in `onPostExecute` you add elements to the same list passed to the adapter. I can try to provide you more code details.

Comment: Hi, yes I have checked and it is. The problem is the `ListView` is not being displayed at all. I have provided the `xml` file also - I think that may be the problem

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz I'm going to check

Comment: You never execute the AsyncTask

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz Layout is fine. I tried it and works ok. I posted update code... Only thing missing is execution of async task.

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz Are you sure code in `onPostExecute` doesn't throw any Exception?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Because when I add some values to the list in `onCreate()` and I run the app those values are there. But when I execute `onPostExecute()` nothing happens

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz What I mean is that I tried code with async task and it works fine. Of course I tried by adding static items in `onPostExecute`. You should check (with LogCat and/or by debugging) if `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is executed (maybe not because of a JSON parsing exception) and if `namesList` is not empty.

Comment: I think I know why now - basically it is saying `namesList.add(names)` or even when I add `namesList.add("Bob")` outside the `for` loop - the IDE is saying that there might be a `NullPointerException`. I don't know why I am getting that

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz `NullPointerException` on `namesList.add("Bob")` means that `namesList` was not initialized. But in your code it is. Only difference with my code is that you wrote `List<String> namesList = new List<String>()` that is not possible because `List` is an interface and cannot be instantiated. That's why I replaced it with `List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103383/discussion-between-thetonrifles-and-samuel-georgeszusz).

Comment: I'm getting somewhere but the code is crashing I believe on the last three lines:      ` result.clear();`
               ` result.addAll(namesList);`
              `  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`