# How can I get the Object value from a callback interface?

Tags: java, android, interface, callback

first question, i'm starting with java programming..

I've got an AssyncTask method that uses an interface to get the User info back once is finished, the call its made from the OnPostExecute. It's all good, but once y receive the data on my main activity I can't extract the User out the done method.

I post the code for better understand.

```
 new FetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, new GetUserCallBack() {

                @Override
                public void done(User returnedUser) {

                    String usernameRet = returnedUser.username;
                    String passwordRet = returnedUser.password;
                }

            });
```

and the interface:

```
public interface GetUserCallBack {

    public abstract void done(User returnedUser);
}
```

AsynkTask:

```
public class FetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {

    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
    User user;
    User ret_user;
    GetUserCallBack usercallback;


    public FetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallBack usercallback){
        this.user  = user;
        this.usercallback = usercallback;

    }


    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> dataToSend = new HashMap<>();
            dataToSend.put("username", user.username);
            dataToSend.put("password", user.password);
            ret_user = rh.sendGetRequest("www.fjrmy.php", dataToSend);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret_user;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
        super.onPostExecute(ret_user);
        usercallback.done(returnedUser);
    }


}
```

I just want to "extract" the usernameRet and the passwordRet out to work with them. Is it possible?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why have you included the JavaScript tag? It's a completely different language.

Comment: post your AsyncTask code

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35210468/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 is there any short explanation about how to do it? it's really simple i just want to extract the info of returnedUser to work with it out of the call.

Comment: what do you think `return null;` does?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `AsyncTask`, you return `null` in the `try` block if the `rh.sendGetRequest` method succeeds, change that to `return ret_user;`.

You also don't seem to call `execute` on your `AsyncTask` in your example code.

```
final User user = new User(); <--- declare a field or outer variable

FetchUserDataAsyncTask task = new FetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, new GetUserCallBack() {
      @Override
      public void done(User retUser) {
          user.username = retUser.username; // <--- set variables
          user.password = retUser.password; // <---
      }
});
task.execute(); // <----- missing this
```

Comment: can you help me with the setName method please?

Answer (score 0):

Your AsnycTask returns always null.
Remove this line:

```
 return null;
```

Also holding on to the return value in the AsyncTask is not required. This should work:

```
public class FetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {

    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
    User user;
    GetUserCallBack usercallback;


    public FetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallBack usercallback){
        this.user = user;
        this.usercallback = usercallback;

    }


    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> dataToSend = new HashMap<>();
            dataToSend.put("username", user.username);
            dataToSend.put("password", user.password);
            return rh.sendGetRequest("www.fjrmy.php", dataToSend);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
        super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
        usercallback.done(returnedUser);
    }


}
```