# Retrieving -1 from JSON Data for not understood reason

Tags: android, json

I am trying to open a connection to a JSON URL http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=frozen&y=&plot=short&r=json. But I am keep retrieving -1 for my data using the code below. I tried to trace where I was going wrong by using `Log.v` and I realized I am actually retrieving -1 from the website and the loop only runs once. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class GetRawData {

private String url;
private String mData;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "GetRawData";

public GetRawData(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public void execute () {
    GetRawDataBackground getRawDataBackground = new GetRawDataBackground();
    getRawDataBackground.execute(url);
}

public class GetRawDataBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private StringBuffer stringBuffer;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        mData = processDownloads (params[0]);

        if (mData == null){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Null returned during processing");
            return null;
        }

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Data retrieved from doInBackground : " + mData);

        return mData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Data retrieved is : " + s);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    private String processDownloads (String mUrl){

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            if (mUrl == null){
                return null;
            }
            URL url = new URL(mUrl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Response code is : " + responseCode);

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            while (reader.readLine() != null){
                stringBuffer.append(reader.read());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "while loop " + stringBuffer.toString());
            }

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "stringBuffer" + stringBuffer.toString());

            return stringBuffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "MalformedURLException");
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException in making connection");
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error attempting to close reader");
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are getting a string of -1? I don't see how thats possible with any of the code you've shown

Comment: yea... that's exactly the problem

Comment: When you log the response code, do you see 200?

Comment: yes I see 200 so it's not with the connection

Comment: One thing thats related to this code is I'm setting `GetRawData getRawData = new GetRawData("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=frozen&y=&plot=short&r=json");
        getRawData.execute();` in the `MainActivity` and that is pretty much all I have related to retrieving data @cricket_007

Comment: Actually, I see the problem. `while (reader.readLine() != null)`... You are consuming the lines of the reader without doing anything with them.

Comment: Oh I thought that was the way to check if there's any lines left? How else do u implement it with BufferedReader? @cricket_007

Comment: I've answered several questions regarding AsyncTask, but I think this is my best. It follows the same concept that the Volley library uses. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35210468/2308683

Comment: ah thank you so much....@cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are ignoring the lines you are reading from the BufferedReader

Try this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
 String line;
 while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     sb.append(line);
 }
 return sb.toString();
```